# Finding frequency of each value in all categorical columns across a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, categorical-data

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'sub_code' : ['CSE01', 'CSE01', 'CSE01', 
                   'CSE02', 'CSE03', 'CSE04',
                   'CSE05', 'CSE06'],
     'stud_level' : [101, 101, 101, 101, 
                  101, 101, 101, 101],
     'grade' : ['STA','STA','PSA','STA','STA','SSA','PSA','QSA']})
```

I would like to do the below

a) get the frequency of each unique value in all categorical columns of a dataframe

I tried the below but it is neither efficient nor elegant

```
df['sub_code'].value_counts() # need to key in column name manually
df['grade'].value_counts() # need to key in column name manually
df.select_dtypes(include='object').value_counts() #produces incorrect output
```

As my real data has more than 200 columns and 100k rows, is there any efficient approach to do this?

I expect my output to be like as shown below. If there is any other better way to show the below output, I welcome that as well. I don't know how else to capture this information in a neat manner. So, please do share your suggestions

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `melt` and `value_counts`:

```
out = (df.select_dtypes(object)
       .melt(var_name="Column", value_name="Value")
       .value_counts(dropna=False)
       .reset_index(name="Frequency")
       .sort_values(by=['Column','Frequency','Variable'], ascending=[True,False,True])
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
     Column Variable  Frequency
0     grade      STA          4
1     grade      PSA          2
2     grade      QSA          1
3     grade      SSA          1
4  sub_code    CSE01          3
5  sub_code    CSE02          1
6  sub_code    CSE03          1
7  sub_code    CSE04          1
8  sub_code    CSE05          1
9  sub_code    CSE06          1
```

Comment: @TheGreat `value_counts` by default drops NA values. Set `dropna=False` in value_counts

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use, `get_dummies`

```
  s=pd.get_dummies(df.drop(columns=['stud_level'])).sum(0).to_frame('Freq').reset_index()
s=s['index'].str.split('\_(?=[A-Z0-9]+$)', expand=True).join(s.iloc[:,-1]).rename(columns={0:'Column',1:'Value'})
```

outcome

```
    Column  Value  Freq
0  sub_code  CSE01     3
1  sub_code  CSE02     1
2  sub_code  CSE03     1
3  sub_code  CSE04     1
4  sub_code  CSE05     1
5  sub_code  CSE06     1
6     grade    PSA     2
7     grade    QSA     1
8     grade    SSA     1
9     grade    STA     4
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted for the help. But I don't wish to explicitly mention column names as I deal with big data and it would not be possible (to mention numerica column names to drop them)

Comment: Appreciate that, like I first stated, my preferred way out was melt, wasn't going to be useful to duplicate @enke answer. Cheers